# Доступ к серверу Tomcat из внешнего мира

Tags: tomcat

Имеется небольшая локальная сеть, на одной из машин которой розвернут сервер Tomcat. Выход в мир через роутер со статичным IP, переадресация стоит на ту же машину. При обращении к томкату по локальной сети все прекрасно работает, но при доступе из вне сервер не дает ответа. Кто подскажет, в какую сторону тут копать.

UPD 1. Конфигурация стандартная, поменял только порт

UPD 2. Порты пробросил

UPD 3. Сервер не отвечает вообще ничего, ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Comment: сервер вообще отдаёт что-то через интернет или вообще не доступен? порты пробросили? tomcat обычно на 8080

Comment: Что за роутер у вас? На нем вы сделали перенаправление статический ip:порт => внутренний ip:порт?
UPD. Увидел, что переадресация есть. Вы уверены, переадресация работает корректно? Достижим ли ПК из внутренней сети с самого роутера?

Comment: Каким образом можно проверить корректность работы переадресации?